# Eclipse icon keeps displaying progress bar every second

Tags: eclipse, progress-bar, flashing

The eclipse icon in my taskbar in windows 10 keeps displaying a progress bar. After going half the way through it interrupts itself and starts from the beginning. The result is a constant flashing of the eclipse icon.
I've disabled automatic building but that didn't work. 
Also when I check the progress tab in eclipse it does not show me any open tasks eclipse is performing.

Any idea what the issue could be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe _Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Automatic Updates_ or _Window > Preferences: General > News_. Do you use Mylyn? Which Eclipse package and version do you use and which additional plug-ins do you have installed?

Comment: I'm working on a quite dated software, so I'm using Eclipse 3.8.2. Fortunately while working the issue seems to have fixed itself somehow. Don't know if it was due to me using Project -> Clean a couple times, or deleting a few projects from the workspace.

Comment: Well, seems this was not the solution.The issue is back again. 
I'm also working on projects that are synchronized with an SVN. 
For the plugins, there are tons of them. It's an Eclipse installation I got prepackaged from my employer. Everything works fine on another workspace. Maybe I should try exporting the workspace settings to the new workspace I'm having the issue with.

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: General > Workspace_ do you have enabled _Refresh using native hooks or pooling_ (or something like that; maybe in 3.8.2 it has a different name).

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't pin the problem down, but I managed to solve it by importing the workspace settings from the other workspace I was using with this Eclipse version.